# Better alternative to polling when waiting for a HTTP request in django?

Tags: django, message-queue, polling

I have a django application that needs to communicate with a backend service. Usually I would do it like this:

```py
def my_view(request, id):
    backend_response = requests.get('http://backend.com/{}/'.format(id))
    return HttpResponse(status=backend_response.status_code)
```

Unfortunately the backend service in this case does not work like that. Instead of including the results in the HTTP response it will send them in a separate HTTP request.

My current approach is to write the results to the database and wait for them in the original request handler:

```py
def my_view(request, id):
    requests.get('http://backend.com/{}/'.format(id))
    while True:
        sleep(1)
        try:
            backend_response = BackendResponse.objects.get(id=id)
            break
        except BackendResponse.DoesNotExist:
            pass
    return HttpResponse(status=backend_response.status_code)
```

This feels very weird to me. Are there better solutions for this problem?

Comment: If you're using Postgresql, you could use its [LISTEN/NOTIFY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-notify.html). If you have a Redis instance around, it has `SUBSCRIBE`.

Comment: Sounds interesting. Can you give an example how this could be used from django?